# Use Oracle on Web App (New Question)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, phpmyadmin

Our database project is about creating a web application where the user can add or edit information. My concern is How do I connect Oracle 11g with my PHP?

Note: Our teacher did not teach us about doing all of these. Our teacher wants us to learn by "self-discovery." Hope you can help.

Comment: I don't get it: do you want to use Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I think she said Oracle.

Comment: So why did you install MySQL amd phpMyAdmin then? phpMyAdmin is **only** for MySQL

Comment: I really don't know what I'm doing. :( I'm just following online tutorials. Do you have any idea what OCi8 is? (Not sure if its the right term) How do I connect oracle with my html? Thank you very much for responding @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: "HTML" can not connect to anything. It's a **static** markup language. You will need PHP, JSP/Java (or something similar) if you want a web application that displays data from a database in the browser. _That_ question is however far too broad

Comment: Oh yes. We are required to use PHP. I'm sorry I'm such a noob. It's really hard for me to do this without anyone teaching me how. So far I'm done coding the design with bootstrap. The only thing I need to do is to link my database to my web app. Do you know how? Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Try the free underground PHP and Oracle manual
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html